# How to run a particular file in subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to check if the process is running by giving the process name and if there i am trying to kill and i want to restart the process again. So inside subprocess.call i give the path for the file i need to call. My question here is inside the (/examples) i have many executable files like example1.py,exmaple2.py etc. When i run this script now it shows process found and then kills it. I need to know how i can pass the particular example that i want to call again from the terminal(like i want to execute example1.py and later another script)

```
#test.py
for process in psutil.process_iter():
if (process.name().startswith('python')) and ("new" in process.cmdline()[1]):
    print('Process found')
    process.kill()
    time.sleep(3)
    subprocess.call('python /Desktop/Test/Script/new/examples', shell=True)
    break
else:
print('Process not found')
```

Comment: Get the script name from `sys.argv` and concatenate it to the directory name.

Comment: @Barmar as you mentioned used sys.argv to take the arguments from command line but then it shows file does not exist

Comment: Did you add the directory prefix when restarting the script?

Answer (score 0):

try to split here

```
subprocess.call('python', '/Desktop/Test/Script/new/examples', shell=True)
```

and be sure you had imported as well

```
#import subprocess
```